# Selenium Grid Helm Chart: Can I Run Multiple Versions Of Chrome Concurrently?

Tags: kubernetes, selenium, helm

I am hosting a Selenium Grid instance in a Kubernetes cluster that was installed using the standard Helm chart. Things are working well but I don't see any value that can be used to install multiple versions of Chrome or Firefox.

Has anyone else tried this?

Comment: You are speaking of creating multiple replicas of the same version of chrome or multiple different versions of Chrome/Firefox at the same time?

Comment: I would like to run multiple different versions of Chrome at the same time.

Comment: Can you provide more details- environment specification/tutorial/config files you are using ?